Git: how to create multiple local branches that don't share the same modified files?
I have a Git repo cloned locally.
I made a branch via
git checkout -b a_new_hope_branch
When checking out/switching between development and a_new_hope_branch I see that they have the same files listed as being modified.
How can I have that not be the case?
Such that the files modified in a_new_hope_branch don't appear as modified in my local development ( or other ) branches?

You should commit or stash any changes before checking out a different branch. git will usually force you to before you can checkout, except in certain cases (like when they won't clobber anything) where they are brought over like you're seeing: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22055552/7411885

if you want to permanently destroy any modified or untracted files in your working directory after switching branches, you can run git reset --hard, but those files/changes will be gone forever and will not come back when you checkout the initial branch again. If you don't want to loose the changes, your choices are to stash or commit prior to checking out. remember you only have 1 working directory, no matter how many branches you have.

Your local modifications in a Git repository aren't part of any branch until they've been committed. Until then, the modifications are kind of "floating" (indeed they can even conflict with branch switching).
The only way to associate them with the branch is to commit them with git commit, and it's somewhat common to just do a "WIP" commit and finish/amend it later. You can always update commits that you haven't published yet.
If you frequently work on multiple branches, use git worktree to check them out simultaneously to their own directories – each of which will have a separate copy of all files and therefore its own local modifications. (It's similar to having multiple clones, except the worktrees do share commit storage so the repository doesn't need to be downloaded again.)

What is a "WIP" commit?

"WIP" is "Work in Progress". eg everything in your working directory that is untracked or tracked but uncommitted gets committed before you change branches.
